# Need max value in a MongoDB collection, and its timestamp

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider a collection consisting of documents of the following form:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55f3600da9fb6e4f937a50a7"),
"timestamp" : ISODate("2010-01-01T08:10:00Z"),
"temperature" : 12.31
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55f3600da9fb6e4f937a50a8"),
"timestamp" : ISODate("2010-01-01T08:15:00Z"),
"temperature" : 12.48
}
...
```

I want to find the max temperature for each day of the year, *and* the time it occurred. The first part is easy enough with a pipeline aggregation:

```
[{"$group" : {"_id" : {"day": { "$dayOfYear": "$timestamp" }},
              "max_temperature": {"$max" : "$temperature"}}},
 {"$sort" : {"_id.day":1}}]
```

This gives me a nice result set with the max temperature for each day:

```
{u'max_temperature': 20.98, u'_id': {u'day': 1}}
{u'max_temperature': 24.15, u'_id': {u'day': 2}}
{u'max_temperature': 22.02, u'_id': {u'day': 3}}
...
```

But, how do I get the *timestamp* of when each daily maximum occurred?
Something like:

```
{u'max_temperature': 20.98, u'time_of_max': ISODate("2010-01-01T15:11:12"), u'_id': {u'day': 1}}
{u'max_temperature': 24.15, u'time_of_max': ISODate("2010-01-02T16:03:42"), u'_id': {u'day': 2}}
{u'max_temperature': 22.02, u'time_of_max': ISODate("2010-01-03T16:33:59"), u'_id': {u'day': 3}}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) first and the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator instead of `$max`. But the catch is you need the "day" detail reduction to be present first:

```js
[
    { "$project": {
        "day": { "$dayOfYear": "$timestamp" },
        "timestamp": 1,
        "temperature": 1
    }},
    { "$sort": { "day": 1, "temperature": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id" : "$day",
        "max_temperature": { "$first": "$temperature" },
        "timestamp": { "$first": "$timestamp" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id":1 } }
]
```

Once you have that projected value for "day" then the input can be ordered by day with the largest "temperature" value first. Then the `$first` grouping operator will pick fields from the "first" document found on the grouping boundary.

So the "temperature" is the "maximum" because of the sort order, and the other fields will be from the same document where that value occurs.

Technically, this should still work:

```js
[
    { "$sort": { "temperature": -1, "timestamp": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id" : { "$dayOfYear": "$timestamp" },
        "max_temperature": { "$first": "$temperature" },
        "timestamp": { "$first": "$timestamp" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id":1 } }
]
```

But as the initial sort order is actually misaligned with the grouping key, then it is likely to loose in overall efficiency.

Comment: Your first suggestion definitely works, and is an approach I had not thought of. Finding the max temperature for each day using the original approach takes about 0.1s on my NUC. Adding the time-of-day using your approach takes about 0.4s. It's a shame that there isn't some way of saving the document that satisfies the `$max` aggregation.

Comment: @TomK The whole point is that what you are "asking for" is "multiple values from a matched document" which is the "opposite" of what `$max` does. The `$max` operator finds the "maximum" from "anywhere" within the grouping condition, but you want "two properties" that occur at the "maximum" grouping boundary, and that means a `$sort` must occur. It's not "my" approach, it's the "only" approach without keeping separate pre-aggregated data. And that last is what we often do for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

> db.temp.aggregate([{$project:{date:{$dayOfYear:"$timestamp"},temp:"$temperatur
>   e",ISODate:"$timestamp"}},{$group:{_id:"$date",maxtemp:{"$max":"$temp"},timestam
>   p:{"$first":"$ISODate"}}},{"$sort":{_id:1}}])

Comment: If I'm understanding your approach correctly, this returns the start time of each day, not the time the max temperature occurred.